# (cache from disk) with Chrome/Safari cache on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cache, safari

I'm having a problem with the cache in Chrome/Safari on macOS. I'm updating my CSS file but the browser refuses download it from my local development machine. I have confirmed changes in compiled CSS file but they are not reflected in developer tools.

I have tried:

- Right clicking refresh button and selecting 'empty cache and hard reload'
- Disabling cache in dev tools
- Restarted my machine
- Cleared cache under 'Clear browsing data'
- Loaded website in an incognito window
- Adding cache busting techniques to assets `...?v=1`

If I disable cache the headers read

```
 200 OK
 Cache-Control:no-cache
```

If I enable cache the headers read

```
 200 OK (from disk cache)
```

Both show the same file. I never get any 304 codes indicating that the server is never seeing a request for the files.

Server environment: Vagrant/CentOS in VirtualBox with NGINX, MariaDB, Redis and Laravel.